# Core Data integer value store through text field

Tags: ios, core-data

In core data inside Person entity I have an attribute `phoneNumber` whose type I have set to integer 64 bit. In ViewController.m, file I am using this code

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *newPerson = [[NSManagedObject alloc]initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
NSString *numberString = [self.phoneNumber text];
NSInteger phoneNumber = [numberString integerValue];
[newPerson setValue:self.firstName.text forKey:@"firstName"];
[newPerson setValue:self.lastName.text forKey:@"lastName"];
[newPerson setValue:phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
```

where firstName, lastName and phoneNumber are text fields. But the last line is giving error as

```
Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'id _Nullable' is disallowed with ARC
```

If I use `self.phoneNumber.text` I don't think the value will be stored in the database since the type there is integer 64-bit. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: In stead of storing it as a number, you should consider storing it as a string and add a validator (using key-value-validation) to strip non-numeric characters. That way you can support phone numbers starting with `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `attribute` type to `integar32` or `integer64` in your model for an entity and when you generate your model class  the type of that attribute is set to `NSNumber` so you should convert your values to `NSNumber` and then set it to your model object. Like the following.

```
NSNumber * phoneNumber =  [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[self.phoneNumber text] intValue]]] ;
[newPerson setValue: phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though the value in the Core Data model is an integer, the `Person` entity expects a number object for the phone number.

First convert the integer to a NSNumber, then you can assign it to person's `phoneNumber` property:

```
NSNumber *phoneNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[numberString integerValue]];
[newPerson setValue:phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
```